# Need help to create a process C# : Combobox > Select item > Accept button > User Control > Panel

Tags: c#, combobox, user-controls, panel

I need help for writing a code in C#, Visual Studio 2015. The thing is, I want to do the following : The user selects an item from the combobox, clicks the accept button afterwards, and a user control connected to the selected item appears in the panel I created. I will also attach a video so you can get a clearer picture of what I need here. Thanks.

The video attached by me on YouTube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2y1G94poWY

Comment: In which part you need help? have you decided which framework to use? Winforms? WPF?

Comment: Winforms, sorry for not mentioning it. I need help in connecting these processes into one to get what i need as i explained.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new Winform application in Visual Studio? After you do that, you can use the Toolbox window to add controls. I think you should start with that and make your question more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simplified version for rapidity:

you could create a windows form as the comments suggest and add a combobox (combobox1) and the panel (panel1) and a button (button1) and hook them up with events.

[image]

See below and I've really made some simple controls but you could make this much more complex.

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.Items.Add("item 1");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("item 2");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("item 3");
        }

```
    private Control myControl;

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            case "item 1":
                //your loading logic here
                myControl = new UserControl();
                myControl.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
                break;
            case "item 2":
                //your loading logic here
                myControl = new UserControl();
                myControl.Controls.Add(new Button());
                break;
            case "item 3":
                //your loading logic here
                myControl = new UserControl();
                myControl.Controls.Add(new ComboBox());
                break;
            default:
                myControl = null;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Clear();
        panel1.Controls.Add(myControl);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me the idea on how to work it out, I made it !